# How spammers are abusing 2fa SMS in web apps?

Tags: multi-factor, spam, sms

My webapp has an SMS 2FA option. When someone enrolls, it sends an SMS to the number specified by the user with hard coded text that contains a token that the user needs to then enter in the web app to confirm the enrollment. Pretty standard.

I've noticed spammers are signing up the service, and enrolling with multiple phone numbers (enrolling again and again).

I am wondering how they gain from such action ? They cannot control the text sent in the SMS, nor the number it's coming from, so what are they gaining from it ?

Comment: *"so what are they gaining from it ?"* - one can only speculate. But it might be just automated, so they don't care. Or there actual goal is to cause costs for you.

Comment: Are they responding to the sms ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it is automated, but still, they have invested time to create the automation so I would assume there's something in it for them

Comment: @RohitGupta I am not sure, would that make a difference ? There's nothing really to respond to, as it's coming from an SMS api as a service

Comment: "they have invested time to create the automation" -- these are pre-built tools...

Comment: @schroeder even tools like headless browsers need to be automated and scripted to know which button to click etc. There's no prebuilt tool for every random webapp

Comment: Does your app have a "enroll/register/sign-up" button? Simple regex handles that without any custom coding ...

Comment: @schroeder yes, but 2fa is not activated by default, you have to navigate multiple screens to turn it on. Anyway, my point was that this is not something done by off-the-shelf vulnerability scanner or tool, it requires some modifications. Not hard, I agree, but still someone invested some time in it, which brought me to the question - What's in it for them... Perhaps there's an attack that I am not aware of.

Comment: It could be something similar to the [sort of fraud from unscrupulous services providers](https://commsrisk.com/elon-musk-says-twitter-lost-60mn-a-year-because-390-telcos-used-bot-accounts-to-pump-a2p-sms/) that led twitter to disable sms 2fa. Are those spammers requesting a large number of authentication codes?